# How to change Dropdown list bullet icon when it opens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, list, drop-down-menu, nav, bullet

I'm trying to learn bootstrap but there is a problem with that. I created a simple dropdown list.
I want that list to have custom bullet icons. And whenever one of the dropdowns opens I want that icon to be changed.

Here is a better example of what I want:
https://i.ibb.co/pP8cC7B/New-Project.png

I want that test1's icon to be custom and when someone clicks that dropdown opens and icon changes.
Also, I want it to be repeatable so I can use it again and again. Inside another dropdown.

Down there I paste the code that I'm working on it. Doesn't matter the code will stay the same or not. Just I want to know how to do that.

```html
   <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          href="#"
          role="button"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"
          >Dropdown</a
        >
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style=>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS only solution. You can customize it further as you wish. Add the following to your CSS styles.

```
a.nav-link[aria-expanded="false"]:before {
content: "> ";
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
a.nav-link[aria-expanded="true"]:before {
content: "v ";
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```